# onClick change the background colour and background image of a link

Tags: html, onclick

Home

I am trying to change the background image and colour of the font for the home link using onClick. But i am unable to achieve the result.Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm sure someone can - can you post some code we can look at?

Comment: Please include what you have already tried.

Comment: If you have any code, showing what you have already tried, it'd be a lot easier. Include some HTML and the javascript you want us to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(element)
{
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png')";
    element.style.color = '#E61E1E';
}
</script>
<div onclick="change(this)" style="width: 128px; height:128px; cursor: pointer;">
    test test test ...
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div onclick="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png\')';this.style.color = '#E61E1E';" style="width: 128px; height:128px; cursor: pointer;">
    test test test ...
</div>
```

Comment: <a href="#target1" class="panel" onclick="change(this)"> Home</a> i tried this on the link while in the javascript tried function change(element)
{
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(../pics/hover.png)";
    element.style.color = '#FFF';
}

Comment: its still not happening

Comment: @user2655647 is your url correct in background parameter? or what is not happening?If you test your code with chrome press ctrl+j and see if there is any errors, as my posted code works with all major browsers. See it on jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/zkWzt/